# Ajax Success Function Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ok so my problem is my Ajax Success Function is not working properly but IS WORKING properly on another web page. Annoying right? They have the same code(copy pasted it and edited) with different variables of course.

Working Code:

```
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'login.php',
        data: {
                uname: username,
                pass: password
              },
       success: function(html){    

      alert(html);
        if(html=='true')    {
         $("#add_err").html("right username or password");
         window.location="../home.php";
        }
        else    {
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
         $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or password"+username+password);

        }
       },

       beforeSend:function()
       {
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
        $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
       }
      });
```

Login.php will just echo the word "true" or "false" depending on the query.

This is the Not Working Code:

```
 $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'loginphp.php',
        data: {
                username1: username,
                password1: password
              },

       success: function(html){    

      alert(html);
        if(html=='true')
        {
            $("#errorlogin").html("right username or password");
            window.location="../php/home.php";
        }
        else 
        {
            $("#errorlogin").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
            $("#errorlogin").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or password"+username+password);
        }           

        },



       beforeSend:function()
       {
        $("#errorlogin").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
        $("#errorlogin").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
       }
      });
```

Loginphp.php will just echo the word "true" or "false" depending on the query.

as you can see they are technically the same but the not working code, what happens is even when the loginphp.php echoed TRUE, success function will go directly to ELSE.

I know it really echoed TRUE because I used "alert(html)" and it really shows TRUE.

But in the working code, the "if(html=='true')" is triggered. I don't know what is happening..

Comment: String comparisons are case sensitive.  Is loginphp.php returning "true" or "TRUE" or some other variation?

Comment: it is returning a string which is exactly "true". I already fixed it but I didn't get to know the real problem.  I just used the working code and substitute the variables.. can you tell me what will I do about this question? is there like a answered already button?

Answer (score 0):

You should unquote to the true:

```
if(html==true) //or just, if(html)
```

Otherwise it will look for string "true" and this is why it goes to the else part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if(html){}` which will run for any value of `html` except for false.

Answer (score 0):

try on login.php at end

```
echo json_encode(array("msg"=>"true"));
```

or on success you can check like this

```
if(html.msg == "true")
{}
```

try it may be help